# Insert Into Multiple Files in Windows shell script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Basically I'm trying to write a batch file to insert some code into multiple files. Here are the details of what I'm tring to accomplish:
1. The input string comes from a file test.txt.
2. The string needs to be inserted as the second line of destination files.
3. Destination files are all the .xml files under the same direction as the batch file.

I suppose I should use a FOR loop to go through all .xml files. Something like

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.xml') do ()
```

I've read though some tutorials and posts but can't find a way to add anything to files in a loop. Using Echo or TYPE doesn't seems to work for each file in a loop. How do I modify files in a loop?
Also to insert to a certain number of line some post say the file needs to be put into a variable. But my files are pretty large, which I don't want to put into variables. Is there another way to insert into a certain line in a file?

Comment: `The string needs to be added to the second line of destination files.` what do you mean? Concatenate with, or insert after or what? Is the file-to-be-added-to a single-line file? Does it exceed ~8K per line? Are you open to TPP solutions?

Comment: @PeterWright Here I want insert, but actually anything method that can write to the second line is good enough. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you want to modify XML files?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes I do. Does it matter what format the file is?

Comment: Yes. Structural elements of XML may begin anywhere in a line and/or may span multiple lines. You could break the format by inserting stuff at the wrong place. You'd be far better off using a language that actually has XML parsing capabilities. VBScript and PowerShell come with the operating system. Perl or Python would be other good alternatives.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I asked how to do it at the second line because I know I should put it at the second line. I did it with a single file and it worked. Basically I only want to do it to multiple files at one time. You are absolutely correct that other languages will do, but I'm only permitted to use DOS batch script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b *.xml') DO (
 SET line2=Y
 (
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%x IN ("%%i") DO (
  ECHO(%%x
  IF DEFINED line2 TYPE Line2.txt
  SET "line2="
 )
 )>"%%~ni.lmx"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you - but it will delete empty lines.

Comment: What does Y in SET line2=Y mean? Also why "%%~ni.lmx" is write in reverse order?

Comment: `line2` is simply an environment variable. Setting it to any value makes it `defined`. Then, in the loop, after writing out the first line of the XML, write out `line2.txt` because `line2` is defined. `line2` is deleted by being set to a zero-length string, so for the remainder of the lines in the XML, `line2.txt` is NOT output because `line2` is not defined. Next file - set `line2` again and process...`%%~ni.lmx` sets up the output file to be the same name as the input (`%%~nx`) + a .lmx extension - just xml reversed. You can't insert in-place, so a new file is created. Just needs renaming..

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /P string=< test.txt
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
   (for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" "%%a"') do (
      if %%b equ 2 echo %string%
      set "line=%%c"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      echo(!line!
      endlocal
   )) > "%%a.new"
)
```

New files have `.xml.new` extension; you may add a couple lines to delete original `.xml` files and rename `.xml.new` ones to `.xml`.